# How to resolve warning: This AsyncTask class should be static or leaks might occur

Tags: java, android

I have the following code:

```
    private class ImageCompressTask extends AsyncTask<Uri, Integer, byte[]> {

        @Override
        protected byte[] doInBackground(Uri... uris) {
            Bitmap bitmap = ImagePicker.getBitmap(getContentResolver(),uris[0]);
            if (bitmap == null) {
                return null;
            }
            Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "doInBackground: MBs before compression: " + (double) bitmap.getByteCount() / 1e6);
            byte[] bytes = getBytesFromBitmap(bitmap, 80);
            Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "doInBackground: MBs after compression: " + (double) bytes.length / 1e6);
            return bytes;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(byte[] bytes) {
            super.onPostExecute(bytes);
            uploadData(bytes);
        }

        private byte[] getBytesFromBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int quality) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, stream);
            return stream.toByteArray();
        }
    }
```

It basically uploaded the image to the storage and new document to the database (firebase). I get the warning:

```
This `AsyncTask` class should be static or leaks might occur.
```

Tried to look into previous threads but didn't find a solution there. If I make the class static then I can't call `getContentResolver()` and `uploadData(bytes)`. How to resolve it?

Comment: Preferably, you use something other than `AsyncTask`. It is deprecated in Android 11 and has been considered to be a bad idea for a few years. Use something else: RxJava, coroutines (when you switch to Kotlin), `Executor` in a `ViewModel`, plain threads in a `ViewModel`, etc. Beyond that, if `uploadBytes()` does what it says, move the code for that directly into `doInBackground()`, as network I/O needs to be done on a background thread. And you can pass a `ContentResolver` into the `ImageCompressTask` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You're apparently dealing with inner class. It keeps reference to hosting class, in your case it is something lifecycle aware like activity or fragment. What you need to do is to:

1. Do not use AsyncTask in the first place (kidding, but with a grain of a salt)
2. Make your ImageCompressTask static as stated
3. Is it an option not to pass content resolver as argument and instead provide your Async task with result of `ImagePicker.getBitmap(getContentResolver(),uris[0])`?
4. Do you network, compression stuff also inside `doInBackground`, use `onPostExecute` only for post processing of any relevant results.